# What is causing this 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'animate' of undefined' error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

All,

See the code below:

```
function menu() {
    this.menuitem=[];
    this.submenu=[];
    this.menuitem[0] = $('div#sivname1');
    this.menuitem[1] = $('div#divname2');
    this.submenu[0] = $('div#submenu1');
    this.submenu[1] = $('div#submenu2');
    this.active = false;
    this.timeout;
}

menu.prototype = {
    animatedown: function(submenu) {
        submenu.animate({top: '99px'}, 200);
    },
    animateup: function(submenu) {
        submenu.animate({top: '-4px'}, 200);
    }
}

var menu = new menu();
z=2;
while(z--) {
    console.log(z);
    menu.menuitem[z].hover(
    function() { //mouseover
        if(menu.active) {
            clearTimeout(menu.submenu[z].data("timeout"));
        }
        else {
            menu.animatedown(menu.submenu[z])
        };
    },
    function() { //mouseleave
        $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout(function({
            menu.animateup(menu.submenu[z])
        },200));
        menu.active = false;    
    }),

    menu.submenu[z].hover(
    function() { //mouseover
        menu.active = true;
        if (menu.menuitem[z].data("timeout")) {
            clearTimeout(menu.menuitem[z].data("timeout"));
        };
    }, 
    function() { //mouseleave
        $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout(function() {
            menu.animateup(menu.submenu[z]);menu.active = false;
        },200));   
    });
}
```

This code gives the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'animate' of undefined

And the strange this is that is I add:

```
z=0;
```

to the bottom of the code it will work properly. I would expect it to work without z=0 and I have no idea why it does when I add that. Can anyone please explain?

The problem was in the closures, the following code works:

```
z=1;
while(z--){
  (function(z) {
    console.log(z);
      menu.menuitem[z].hover(
        function(){ //mouseover
          if(menu.active){clearTimeout(menu.submenu[z].data("timeout"));}
          else{menu.animatedown(menu.submenu[z])};
        }, 
        function(){ //mouseleave
          $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout(function(){menu.animateup(menu.submenu[z])},200));
          menu.active = false;    
        }
      )

      menu.submenu[z].hover(
        function(){ //mouseover
          menu.active = true;
          if(menu.menuitem[z].data("timeout")){clearTimeout(menu.menuitem[z].data("timeout"));};
        }, 
        function(){ //mouseleave
          $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout(function(){menu.animateup(menu.submenu[z]);menu.active = false;},200));   
        }
      );
  })(z); //this is to enable closures http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures
}
```

Comment: what is `animateup` and `animatedown`?

Comment: I have added the animateup and animatedown code.

Comment: It looks like it's a case of using a single variable in several functions, but expecting the variable to be different in each function. Read [this](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures) ("Closures Inside Loops").

Comment: I don't get any errors in that code. Returns 1 then 0 to the console. (http://jsfiddle.net/uv6Aw/)

Comment: @j08691 you have **no** html there to test it....

Comment: @Neal - I assumed the error he described resulted simply from his code and the console log calls.

Comment: @j08691 the OP was talking about an error in the `animate` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** of all, you have an error in the code:

```
$(this).data("timeout", setTimeout(function({
    menu.animateup(menu.submenu[z])
},200));
```

Should be:

```
$(this).data("timeout", setTimeout(function() {
    menu.animateup(menu.submenu[z]);
},200);
```

**Second:** `z` is global, and your callbacks will use it's last value after the initialization. You should create a local copy of `z` for your callbacks with a closure in the loop, like this:

```
while (z--) {
    (function(z) {
        /* your code */
    })(z);
}
```

This way you enclose the value of `z` for that while cycle, and the callbacks in it.

**The *strange* thing** with `z=0` is that, when the loop dies (since `z` is 0) the decrementing operator will run one more time, and `z` will be -1. The -1 index will be used in all your callbacks, indexing a non-object which don't have animate ofc. But (!) if you set it `z=0`, than it will index an object, but always the one with the 0 index. You have to use the above correction to get the good result in every menuitem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `submenu` item is most probably **not** a jQuery object.

You have **no** `submenu[2]` which is where your `z` variable starts at.

You might want to switch it to:

```
while(--z) ...
```

Which should start your `z` at 1.

Comment: `--z`/`z--` only differ in their return value, which is not used here. Inside the `while` loop `z` is never `2`.